# Using sizeof template parameters pack in class template specialization

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, language-lawyer, variadic-templates

Check of correcteness during compilation of the following code (metafunction for selection of a type from a type list by right to left 1-based index) failed on *GCC*, whereas *clang* accepts this code:

```
#include <cstdlib>

template< std::size_t i, typename ...types >
struct at_index
{

};

template< typename first, typename ...rest >
struct at_index< (1 + sizeof...(rest)), first, rest... >
{
    using type = first;
};

template< std::size_t i, typename first, typename ...rest >
struct at_index< i, first, rest... >
        : at_index< i, rest... >
{

}; 

int main()
{
}
```

Which compiler is right?

GCC error message:

```
error: template argument '(1 + sizeof... (rest))' involves template parameter(s)
 struct at_index< (1 + sizeof...(rest)), first, rest... >
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I think the types from parameter pack in `sizeof...` operator should not be resolved into some parts of symbol names. Therefore no name mangling problems should be here.

Is this a *clang* extension to allow above code?

Comment: the problem occurs regardless of the order of parameters [example](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/4fmoBTqwQbRhe5wU)

Comment: the workaround could be to use `std::integral_constant` instead of non-type template parameter [example](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/oEeClM4wgFXCXk4g). Not sure if your code is valid though...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

N4140 [temp.class.spec]/8.1:

> A partially specialized non-type argument expression shall not involve
>   a template parameter of the partial specialization except when the
>   argument expression is a simple *identifier*.

This has since been relaxed by [core issue 1315](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0263r1.html#1315). Presumably GCC hasn't gotten around to implementing that yet.